# How to set memory I/O ranges on dedicated Parallel Card

Tags: windows

Good Morning, I have a PCI parallel card that I need to manually set the I/O range on, yet the "Use Automatic Settings" box is grayed out. This is to connect a BDI programming device.

[image: Parallel Ports Settings Screen]

Answer (score 0):

Plug and Play Parallel cards automatically select the DMA range and I/O range. There does not appear to be a way to remap the cards in Windows 7. You will need to purchase a special card such as [this one](http://www.startech.com/Cards-Adapters/Parallel/1-Port-PCI-Parallel-Adapter-Card-with-Re-mappable-Address~PCI1PM) in order to get the custom I/O ranges that you need.

Source: StarTech Technical Support